# How to improve Konva resize performance while resizing

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm using [konva](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyRAo.png) js framework to render hall map. I implemented zoom function, and found that it can take a long time(about 2,5 sec) if hall is big enoung.

The problem is this long calculations rerforms inside the konva code. Can i hasten it a little?

[Performance trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyRAo.png)

My js zoom js function is:

```
zoomKonvaIn: function (el) {
    var scaleBy = 1.1;
    var stage = $(el.data('mfw_konva')).data('konva');
    var oldScale = stage.scaleX();
    var newScale = oldScale * scaleBy;
    if (newScale < 3) {
        stage.scale({x: newScale, y: newScale});
        stage.size({width: stage.initWidth * newScale, height: 
        stage.initHeight * newScale});
        stage.batchDraw();
    }
    return {
        doing: false,
        addParams: ''
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use SUPER large stage or super complex styles in your page?

As I can see Konva spent almost 1.5s for just changing width property. That is a lot.

How many nodes do you have in your stage?

Comment: yes, its pretty large. About 1000 nodes.

Comment: Then try to apply some performance fixes: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html

Answer (score 1):

cache your drawing before zooming ...

https://konvajs.github.io/docs/performance/Shape_Caching.html